# How do you determine when and where to use a for loop in programming?

Tags: programming-languages

How do you determine when and where to use a for loop in programming?

Comment: Are you referring to loops in *general*, or are you referring to using a `for` loop instead of another kind of loop such as a `while` loop?

Comment: Use a language without `for` loops then you won't need to wonder about this.

Comment: generally, whenever i am iterating over a list of objects, and there is no need for queue keeping, and no need to change the collection while iterating, i go with a `foreach`, otherwise, backwards for-loops, or even while loops

Comment: If you copy the same code more than 100 times, you should use a for loop. If you copy it 99 times, you might think about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is good to use the `for` loop when you know how many iterations you have to do, depending on a value. 
At the opposite, you should use the `while` loop when your loop have to stop depending on a different type of parameter.
Let's see two example in C++ :

### For loop

Here we have a very simple case of using the for loop

```
int StopValue = 10
for ( int i = 0; i<StopValue ; i++)
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

### While loop

Here we have a simple chained List, which we would like to check how many link we have :

```
struct Node {
    int x;
    Node *nextNode;
}

// Declaration & initialization of your chained list

// Check how many link we have 
Node* head= YourFirstNode;
int NumOfLink =0; 
while (head->nextNode != nullptr)
{
    NumOfLink ++;
    head = head->nextNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops are used to perform the same operation to different data in sequence.

If loop exit condition is known in advance, you can use a for loop.